# jQuery popover with drag and drop facility

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, popover

I am trying to implement jquery popover with drag and drop facility. but not able to complete.
any suggestion ? or is there any library available for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI is probably what you're looking for. See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

For a basic dialog box you would do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Example">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

Remember to include reference to the library as well.

By default the dialog box has drag and drop functionality. However, there are lots of settings you can change to get it exactly how you want.